# How to remove items from an array on a checkout page

Tags: javascript, arrays, cart, shopping-cart

New to JS and trying to create a simple shopping cart using only vanilla JS. I have an item with details and an image that populates on a shopping cart page. I need to have a delete button that allows items to be removed individually from the shopping cart page. Below is the snippet of code I'm having trouble with:

```
function deleteProduct(i) {
alert('i : ' + i)

productArr2.splice(i,1)
console.log(productArr2)}
```

And below is the full JS code in case it would be helpful for debugging. Any help is appreciated!:

```
//Global Variables
var quantity = "";
var glazes = "";
var img = "";
var addItem = "";


//Changes price when quantity is selected 
function priceCounter(){
    var price = document.getElementById("price-details");
    price.innerHTML =  document.getElementById("quantity").value;
}
function setImage(select){
  var image = document.getElementsByName("image-swap")[0];
  image.src = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
}  

function items(title, quantity, glaze, price, img){
    this.title = title;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.glaze = glaze;
    this.price = price;
    this.img = img;
}

//Add to Cart Functionality
function addToCart() {
    var quantityCount = document.getElementById("quantityCount");
    quantityCount.innerText = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    document.getElementById("quantityCount").style.visibility = "visible";


    title = document.getElementsByClassName("productTitle");
    quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    glazing = document.getElementById("glazing").value;
    price = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    img = "images/blackberry-bag.png"
    addItem = new items(title, quantity, glazing, price, img);

    window.localStorage.setItem(localStorageCount, JSON.stringify(addItem));
    // localStorageCount += 1;
}

//creates array to hold bag items
var productArr = []
var productArr2 = []

class Product {
    
    
    constructor(quantity, glaze) {
        this.quantity = quantity
        this.glaze = glaze
    }
}


function addToCart() {
    var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity').value
    var glaze = document.getElementById('glaze').value

    var bun = new Product(quantity, glaze)
    productArr.push(bun)
    
    updateCartNumber(productArr.length)
}

function goToCheckoutPage() {
    alert("taking you to your cart")
    localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(productArr))

    window.location.replace("cart.html")
}
function checkoutPageLoaded() {
    var loadedProductArr = localStorage.getItem('order')
    var productArr2 = JSON.parse(loadedProductArr)
    console.log(productArr2)

    var cart = document.getElementById("cart")

    for(var i = 0; i < productArr2.length; i++) {
        var cinbun = productArr2[i]
        var cinbunGlaze = cinbun.glaze
        var cinbunQuantity = cinbun.quantity

        cart.innerHTML += "<div class='cart-items'> Flavor: Pumpkin Spice Glaze: <img src="+ cinbunGlaze +"> Price: "+ cinbunQuantity +"</div>"
        cart.innerHTML += "<span onclick= 'deleteProduct(" + i + ")'> Delete </span>"
        
    }
}
function saveEdits() {
    localStorage.setItem('order', JSON.stringify(productArr2))
}

function deleteProduct(i) {
    alert('i : ' + i)
    
    productArr2.splice(i,1)
    console.log(productArr2)

}


function updateCartNumber(num) {
    var cartCount = document.getElementById('quantityCount')
    cartCount.innerHTML = num
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but I don't see any sort of AJAX calls here. The cart contents should be server driven if possible. The general workflow should be when a user clicks a button to change the cart contents (deleting, adding, etc), you should show loading UI, then let the server know about the change, and then return the new cart from the server. It keeps things in sync.

Comment: The most likely issue is that the array is zero-based - meaning the splice should be one less than the expected index. If you have an array of [ 2, 4, 77 ], .splice(1,1) would remove the 4